# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index

Tags: c#, selenium

I am a beginner for selenium with C# .. When i was trying the below code , it is throwing the exception:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>
> Parameter name: index

please help me on this

```
class Program { static void Main(string[] args)
{

    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Url = @"file:///C:/users/user/documents/visual%20studio%202012/Projects/LearnSelenium_Xpath/LearnSelenium_Xpath/TestPage.html";
    var radiobutton = driver.FindElements(By.Name("Color"))[0]; -->Exception
    radiobutton.Click();
}
```

Comment: You are not getting element by Find, first check the length / count before accessing index

Answer (score 0):

The `.FindElements` does not seem to find any element, causing the `[0]` to fail.

You should check the result of `driver.FindElements(By.Name("Color"))` before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't be certain that a radio button will be found, or a length error occurred, and a check to notify the user gracefully is in order.

```
class Program { static void Main(string[] args)
{

    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Url = @"file:///C:/users/user/documents/visual%20studio%202012/Projects/LearnSelenium_Xpath/LearnSelenium_Xpath/TestPage.html";
    try
    {
        var radiobutton = driver.FindElements(By.Name("Color"))[0]; -->Exception
        radiobutton.Click();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message(), "Radio button error");
    }
}
```